# representation of the number -1, which is of type int16_t, in binary notation

Tags: objective-c

I want to write a representation of the number -1. How to write a representation of the number -1, which is of type int16_t, in binary notation?

Comment: All 1's.  All modern architectures use 2's-complement to represent negative numbers in binary.  Thus, -1 at any bit-width will simply be all 1's.

Comment: so  do you mean that 1 in binary notation is 1 . and -1 in binary notation is 1's?

Comment: 4-bit examples for brevity: `0001` == 1.  `1111` == -1.

Comment: you wrote for 4-bit . but I need int16_t that looks like 16 bit. will it be 1111111111111111?

Comment: To quote myself: *Thus, -1 at any bit-width will simply be all 1's.*

Comment: If you are unable to understand what Avi is telling you then I doubt you actually need to know what you ask.

Comment: is int16_t a 16-bit or not? I understand what he is telling

Comment: YES!  He's telling you it's `1111111111111111` in binary.

Comment: I found it int16_t is a 16bit integer